# Android MediaPlayer bombs at random on http MP3 stream

Tags: android, media-player

The data is being pulled from a remote server in small increments, based on NPR
s StreamProxy method [here](http://code.google.com/p/npr-android-app/source/browse/trunk/Npr/src/org/npr/android/news/StreamProxy.java?r=100).  The data is sent to the outputstream in small chunks.  Here are all of the details I have collected:

- Randomly throws Socket exceptions, namely Broken Pipe exception.
- I have a feeling this is because the media player begins reading this data before it has enough in the socket and see's partially formatted data(maybe only half of the ID3 info) and then dies.
- I have logging on onInfo and OnError listeners for the MediaPlayer.  For OnInfo() successful streams will deliver what=1/extra=44 and unsuccessful streams often report what=1/extra=26.  OnError deilvers an error with what=1/extra=-1.
- Removing id3 info will often fix this(i think this is related to 2nd bullet)
- It differs per device as to what play(PVPlayer backend is the worst)

Any ideas on this one?  I think it has to do with how the MediaPlayer should wait until is has xx bytes of data before parsing.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to use something like wireshark to view the datapackets being sent and view where the media player stops listening.  This will allow us to parse the metadata to see if it dies on album art parsing.  Any other ideas to use for packet sniff?

Comment: For those of you who have the same issue, I would look into timeout issues with the mediaplayer, as if it doesnt get data fast enough, it will timeout and stop listening to the socket.

Comment: How do you know this? Do you know how long the mediaplayer takes before timing out? I'm very curious ...

Comment: Not exactly, but I suppose it depends on the version.  You can dig through the C code to find out more specifically.  I think PVPlayer is available.